# Where do we keep integration tests in microservices projects?

Tags: java, integration-testing, microservices, test-pyramid

Let's suppose we're talking about a microservices project. Then we usually have different repositories for each microservice. Unit tests, component tests (low layers of test pyramid) are often kept in the same repository with the microservice itself.

But what about integration tests (testing different services together) - in which repository do we keep them? Do we create a separate repository for integration tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration tests are saved in a separate source folder. These tests are different from unit tests in that they use real data and/or thirds party APIs. As a result they tend to be slower as they make network requests, perform database queries, and use large data sets instead of mocking data. This answer on [software engineering stackechange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340347/should-i-separate-unit-tests-and-integration-tests) goes into more detail.